# Пропускается присваивание значения при создании объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

#### Описание

В игре у меня есть фигуры которым управляет скрипт `Figure.js`. В этом скрипте нам интересует вот какой момент:

```cs
public class Figure: MonoBehaviour {
    private static readonly Board.CellType[][,] _Figures = new Board.CellType[][,] { 
        #region N1
        new Board.CellType[,] {
            { Board.CellType.Block },
        },
        #endregion
        ...
    };
    private void Start() {
        Data = _Figures[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, _Figures.Length)]; // Выбор случайных данных
        ...
    }
    public Board.CellType[,] Data;
}
```

В `Start`-е присваивается значение переменной `Data`. То есть как только создается фигура, у переменны `Data` должно быть значение. Но вот незадача:

```cs
public class Gameplay: MonoBehaviour {
    private void Start() {
        Figures = new GameObject[_Spawnpoints.Length];
        ConfigureFigures();
    }
    [SerializeField] private RectTransform[] _Spawnpoints; // Значение передано через Inspector
    public GameObject[] Figures;
    public GameObject PrefabFigure; // Значение передано через Inspector
    public void ConfigureFigures() {
        #region Проверка количества фигуров
        if (Array.TrueForAll(Figures, (figure) => figure == null)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _Spawnpoints.Length; i++) {
                var spawnpoint = _Spawnpoints[i];
                var figure = Instantiate(PrefabFigure, spawnpoint.position, new Quaternion(), spawnpoint);
                Figures[i] = figure;
                ...
            }
        }
        #endregion
        for (int i = 0; i < Figures.Length; i++) {
            var figure = Figures[i];
            if (figure != null) {
                Debug.Log(figure.GetComponent<Figure>().Data);
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

В другом скрипте создается клон фигуры из prefab-а и чуть ниже вывожу на консоль. Получаю `Null`.

[image]

Почему? Непонятно.

#### Вопрос

**Вот очень хотел бы узнать - почему не присваивается значение? Как можно это исправить?**

#### П. Н.

Переменная `Data` нигде больше не используется кроме этих скриптов.

Comment: Вот не знаю как вам, а я не вижу ни единого символа на эти картинках

Comment: @АлексейШиманский когда нажимаете на картинку и она открывается в полном размере тоже не видно?

Comment: "Не видел смысла передать код как текст, как так он огромный" --- то есть опубликовать огромные скрины с тем же количеством текста (на которых ничего не видно) - норм, а сам текст - не норм?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский хотя у меня экран большой. Сейчас что-то предпримем. :-)

Comment: Зачем на что-то нажимать и куда-то перходить, чтобы что-то разглядеть а потом ещё и закрывать,   потом если забыл дорассмотреть - опять нажимать опять переходить, если можно прямо здесь и сейчас смотреть текст?  А вот с телефона как смотреть?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский теперь как?

Comment: Гораздо лучше. Текст ошибки бы тоже цитатой вставить и было бы красиво и понятно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский там ошибка и не используется. Это просто показано, что вывод - `null`.

Comment: Вопросов больше чем ответов. что за переменная Figures в методе `Gameplay::ConfigureFigures`? Где она заполняется и как?  Что за метод `Board.CheckFigureAvailabilty`? Ведь именно в нём ошибка. .... Т.е. показаны не те места даже и с data не связано (пока не видна связь)......... Пока в текущем состоянии проще вам взять отладку и пробежаться ею по коду...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `Gameplay::ConfigureFigures` вызывается в `Start`-е  скрипта`Gameplay`. Подправил в вопросе. `Board.CheckFigureAvailabilty` бесполезный в данном вопросе метод - удалил.

Comment: Всё же я рекомендую отладку))) Пока что такое ощущение, что _Figures  в Figure никак не заполняется и он массив просто пустой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский со странным решением, но у меня получилось. Сейчас покажу ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Из документации**... которая расписывает эту "странную" ситуацию, причем в первых строках...

[MonoBehaviour.Start()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html), первый абзац:

> Start вызывается во фрейме, когда скрипт включается непосредственно
> перед первым вызовом любого из методов Update.

[MonoBehaviour.Awake()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html), первый абзац:

> Awake вызывается, когда активный GameObject, содержащий сценарий,
> инициализируется при загрузке сцены, или когда ранее неактивный
> GameObject становится активным, или после инициализации GameObject,
> созданного с помощью Object.Instantiate. Используйте Awake для
> инициализации переменных или состояний перед запуском приложения.

Answer (score 0):

#### Предположение

Куча отладок показали, что после `Instantiate` `Data` так и остается `null`. Видимо `Start` работает чуть позже чем `Instantiate` (скорее всего в следующем кадре).

#### Решение

Решение не лучшее что могло бы быть и объяснить эту странную ситуацию, но оно помогло. Только строку присваивания данных переносим из `Start` в `Awake`:

```cs
public class Figure: MonoBehaviour {
    private static readonly Board.CellType[][,] _Figures = new Board.CellType[][,] { 
        #region N1
        new Board.CellType[,] {
            { Board.CellType.Block },
        },
        #endregion
        ...
    };
    private void Awake() {
        Data = _Figures[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, _Figures.Length)]; // Выбор случайных данных
    }
    private void Start() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, на форуме пишут как раз: Start runs before the first Update call on a GameObject. Which means it's delayed.....If you want something that runs immediately, try Awake.

It's all documented here. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Ссылка на форум: https://forum.unity.com/threads/monobehaviour-start-after-instantiate-gameobject-in-start-immediately-or-postponed-after-start.456026/

Comment: Регионы зло....